# How to correlate Google Analytics virtual pageviews to events

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to correlate Virtual Pageviews to Events in Google Analytics. When I look into Behavior > Events > Top Events and set Page as the secondary dimension, it says "(not set)".

As I understand, an event doesn't have a parameter to set which page it originates from. Is it automatically determined?

What I want to achieve is make a view that shows the total of pageviews for a (virtual) page, then show a breakdown of all the events for that page. Is that possible?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Welcome to stack you may want to read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic it will help you understand which types of questions can be asked here.

Answer (score 0):

If that was a virtual pageview, you won't get the page dimension in the events reports. However, with this event, you can override the page dimension in GTM (assuming you are using GTM).

You need to click on the **`Enable overriding settings in this tag`** and then place your virtual page URL in there. Example below.

[image]